# Xamarin iOS in Visual Studio is requested to be installed despite the fact that it already has been

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

All of our Xamarin devs (4 on the team) have started to experience the same error while opening Xamarin.Forms iOS-specific project in Visual Studio 2015. The project fails to load with an error dialog like this:

[image]

Clicking install will trigger the installer that will:
[image]
but then, since obviously Xamarin iOS is installed, will say that nothing new is there to install:

[image]

So basically, the mystery of why Xamarin iOS project won't open remains. Any hint would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you say skip?

Comment: @Cheesebaron One would be left with the solution opened in Visual Studio and the Xamarin iOS project not loaded due to this error.